# How to execute different @Before in JUnit

Tags: junit, junit4

Currently If I write @Before method, it will be executed for each of tests present in the JUnit. However i want the following.

I need to have multiple @Before methods and only needed should be executed for each test.

```
Example:
 @Before
  setUpBeforeForTest1AndTest3()

 @Before
 setUpBeforeForTest2AndTest4()
```

For test1 and test2, setUpBeforeForTest1AndTest3() should be executed and for other tests setUpBeforeForTest2AndTest4 should be executed.

How i can acheive this?

Comment: why do you want 2 tests with different setup to be in the same class? what's the actual goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not achieve that this way.

To do this, make 2 distinct test classes, one with test 1 and test 3, one other with test 2 and test 4.

If you have common methods needed in all your test classes either externalize them in a helper or make a super class (usually called 'TestBase' or something similar) providing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Junit

> @Rule TestName

Then in your

> @Before, depending on the test method name, do something differently.